# Slopes of classical newforms

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms

Let $f$ be a newform in $S_k(\Gamma_1(Np^r))$ with $r\geq 1$, and let $a_p$ be the $U_p$ eigenvalue of $f$.

If $f$ is in $S_k(\Gamma_0(Np^r))$, it seems to be a well known consequence of Atkin-Lehner theory that the slope of $a_p$ (the $p$-adic valuation of $a_p$) is equal to $k/2-1$ if $r=1$ and is $\infty$ (i.e. $a_p=0$) if $r\geq 2$.

What happens for general newforms $f \in S_k(\Gamma_1(Np^r),\chi)?$ It is no longer true that if $r\geq 2$ then $a_p=0$. However, does there exist a simple description as above of the slope of $a_p$ only in terms of $r$ and the conductor of $\chi$? For example, it seems to be suggested by examples in the LMFDB that if $r\geq 2$, the slope is going to be infinite unless the order of $\chi$ is divisible by $p^{r-1}$.

Thanks!

Comment: Theorem 3 in Li, "Newforms and functional equations" gives you some information about $a_p$, in particular its vanishing. Also, if $a_p$ is nonzero then you can relate it with the pseudo-eigenvalue of $f$ for the Atkin-Lehner operator at $p$, see Theorem 2.1 in Atkin--Li, "Twists of Newforms and Pseudo-Eigenvalues of W-Operators". The theorem you mention follows directly from this.

Comment: Thanks! To summarize for the benefit of anyone interested, Theorem 3 of Li's article specializes to the following. If $f\in S_k(\Gamma_1(Np^r),\chi)$ with $N$ coprime to $p$ and $r\geq 1$, then the slope is determined by the conductor $cond(\chi)$ of $\chi$ and by $r$. If the $cond(\chi)\nmid Np^{r-1}$, then the slope is $(k-1)/2$. Otherwise, assume $cond(\chi) \mid Np^{r-1}$. If $r=1$ then the slope is $k/2-1$. If $r\geq 2$ then the slope is $\infty$.

Comment: In the case $\chi$ is $p$-primitive, I don't think you can deduce the slope: one only knows the archimedean absolute value. In the particular case $a_p$ is real, we can conclude. Note that pseudo-eigenvalues of $W_p$ are algebraic numbers but not necessarily $\pm 1$, if I recall correctly they may have non-trivial $p$-adic valuations.

Comment: Sorry, you are right of course (I was just about to write a correction...). In the case $cond(\chi)\nmid Np^{r-1}$ and $r=1$ you can conclude that the absolute value of $a_p$ as a complex number is $p^{(k-1)/2}$, but that's not the same as saying the slope is $(k-1)/2$. Thanks for the correction

Comment: Another reference: Mazur, Tate, Teitelbaum, On p-adic analogues of BSD, Section 12